# how to run a function when context changes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-context

Is it possible to run a function in a component whenever, the context changes. I have a variable called `isLoggedIn` in the `Navbar` component. Whenever someone logs in the `isLoggedIn` is changed to `true`. In my `Blog` component how do I make a function call an API to render the comments for example.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, I think you need a useEffect with a dependency as the isLoggedIn variable

Comment: @DougHill As in hind sight it does. So I am using the context API for the logged in state. And whenever the loggedin variable changes I want to run a function that connects to an API. But I dont need to run this function all the time, only when one specific component is rendered.

Comment: @DougHill actually you are correct. This is the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your variable as a state:

```
const [isLoggedIn,setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
```

Whenever you want to change the state of "isLoggedIn" you can call the function:

```
setIsLoggedIn(NEWSTATE);
```

And by using isLoggedIn state in your render, it will automatically change re-render when changing it.